# Apex Code maximum trigger recursion depth with allOrNone false allows successful DML?

Tags: trigger, bug

We recently changed some logic in a trigger, and some of the updates in the trigger mysteriously started to fail. Afterwards, we set up a simple test case to see if we could locate the cause of the problem, which led us to this very simple trigger:

```
trigger recursionLimit on Account (after insert, after update) {
    Database.update(Trigger.new.deepClone(true), false);
}
```

Instead of failing with a fatal exception, the update instead allows the initial DML to complete successfully, with the following logs:

```
32.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,ERROR;CALLOUT,ERROR;DB,ERROR;SYSTEM,ERROR;VALIDATION,ERROR;VISUALFORCE,ERROR;WORKFLOW,ERROR
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|EXECUTION_STARTED
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q40000000LLkR|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
hh:mm:ss.SSS (xxxxxxxxx)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|recursionLimit on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [001____________]
```

Shouldn't the governor limit system prevent this transaction from completing successfully? Is this a bug, or by design? If it's by design, then why does it return Internal Salesforce.com Error results all the way up the stack?

---

### Edit

It appears that try-catch blocks also catch this exception:

```
trigger recursionLimit on Account (after insert, after update) {
    try {
        update Trigger.new.deepClone(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```